# How to decrese mysql connections count?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On my site every user works with database (add some information, get it, change it). Server has limitation to 30 simultaneous connections per db user.

I can't change configuration.

When number of users online is more than 850-950, connection to db (php+mysqli) returns an error. I tried to create more users for database, but hosting staff removed all of them.

How can I reduce number of connections?

What I've already done:

Reduced frequency of regular requests to server (getting new messages, saving text (like  draft)).

Removed queries like save last time when user do something.

Reduced frequency of saving statistic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this(its called a singleton pattern):

```
class Database {
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host;
    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_database;

    /*
    Get an instance of the Database
    @return Instance
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Constructor
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setUsername('root');
        $this->setPassword('');
        $this->setDatabase('testbd');

        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);

        // Error handling
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(),
            E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    // Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
    private function __clone() { }

    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection()  {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $host
     */
    public function setHost($host) {
        $this->_host = $host;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->_username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->_password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $database
     */
    public function setDatabase($database) {
        $this->_database = $database;
    }
}

class Query extends Database {
    public static function run($sql) {
        return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql);
    }

    public static function escape($string) {
        return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->real_escape_string($string);
    }

    public static function error() {
        return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->error;
    }
}
```

To run a query, call `Query::run($sql);` it'll return a mysqli result object.

Comment: If I've understood it rigth, this pattern used to guarantee that we do not have two connections (or more) in one process? I don't have this problem, I create one mysqli object in first lines of script and use it everywhere.

Comment: Whenever a user accesses a script that connects to a db, it automatically creates a new connection. This pattern ensures the server only creates one connection for the user.